# Comboxbox auto select first item when data is available

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am looking for way to select the first item when data became available. But if no data in the source , then do not select. How to do it ? I am very new to WPF.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"
          IsEditable="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static l:DirectXResolution.Resolutions}}"
          ToolTip="Resolutions">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <l:ResolutionConverter x:Key="resolutionConverter"/>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource resolutionConverter}">
            <Binding Path="GameWidth" Mode="OneWayToSource"/>
            <Binding Path="GameHeight" Mode="OneWayToSource"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ComboBox.Text>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Is there any kind of change notification available from the Itemssource (Resolutions)?

Comment: the item source is just List<string> . Not sure if it has change notification. How to add change notification ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way is to use SelectedIndex. Please, check the code below.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"
          IsEditable="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static l:DirectXResolution.Resolutions}}"
          ToolTip="Resolutions"
          SelectedIndex="0">
....
```

Comment: not entirely correct.. need to have IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem= "true" if item list being re-populated otherwise it won't auto select the first index.

Answer (score 1):

`DirectXResolution.Resolutions` must be `ObservableCollection<T>` otherwise your `ComboBox` will not be updated when the data becomes available. You can use `CollectionChanged` event of `ObservableCollection<T>` to select the first item.

If `DirectXResolution.Resolutions` is not `ObservableCollection`, create a wrapper for this collection and inherit `INotifyCollectionChanged`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in code:

```
Items.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (!Items.Contains(Selected))
    {
        Selected = Items.FirstOrDefault();
    }
};
```

`Items` is an `ObservableCollection` that may be updated. `Selected` is a two-way property of the selected item. This code should be placed in the constructor of your view-model.