# WPF Combobox in TableView can't show first item as default

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, tableview, gridcontrol

I'm using `Combobox` in `TableView`, and i want to show the first item text as its default value, i tried to add `SelectionIndex=0`, but it didn't work, its default value is empty. Different with other question like

[Comboxbox auto select first item when data is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604583/comboxbox-auto-select-first-item-when-data-is-available)

my combobox belongs to `TableView`, each item has a combobox(actually each grid item has many types of combobox), so i can't use some methods need to handle it one by one.

my code is as below, and the itemsource **Cities** is a Dictionary, and i use `DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Value"` to show its value(not key):

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="FloorSetUp" Header="Type" MinWidth="20"  HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" VisibleIndex="1">
  <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
           <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Cities}" SelectedIndex="0"/>
      </DataTemplate>
  </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

Anyone can solve this problem?thanks very much!

Comment: You're not binding `SelectedValue` or `SelectedIndex` to anything. If all you want to do is default to selecting the first item, `SelectedIndex="0"` should do it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, Sorry, I pasted incomplete code, i add `SelectedIndex="0"` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then bind SelectedValue to a VM property that's equal to the Value of the item you want to select.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, as i mentioned, each tableview item has a combobox, how can i set selected item for each combobox, a list of string in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Is FloorSetUp also `KeyValuePair<T,R>`?

becuse if not, thats your problem.

The ComboBox has to work with data of same types both in items source and in selected item property.

Comment: `FloorSetUp` is Dictionary<int, string> type, will it work?

Comment: An item in Dictionary<int, string> is KeyValuePair<int, string> so possibly

Comment: then my code satisfies your suggestion, but the result is as i said, default value is empty.